# Copying Okular notes form Windows to Ubuntu

Tags: kde, pdf, transfer, okular, annotation

I have many PDF-files with Okular-notes on them in Windows. Now I would like to copy them into my Linux system. **Okular-notes** are not saved within the PDF-files.

In Linux annotations are located in `~/.kde/share/apps/okular/docdata`, but on my **Windows machine** all I can find is the path `C:\ProgramData\KDE\share\pps\okular`, nothing like `docdata`.

If anyone should know about the **windows path** I need, or has another way to help me keep all my PDF-notes at once, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows all files can be found in `C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\.kde\share\apps\okular\docdata`.